# Find a label for each group given by time sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe, based on the event (so only rows with `event == 1` are getting grouped happening over an irregular time index `t`.  The thing is that `event` happens in a sequence and not in a defined `timerange`. Basically I want that each sequence of `event == 1` gets a different `group` label.

```
x = c(10, 9 ,8,8,8,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,12)
event = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
t = 1:length(x)
df = data.frame(x, event,t)
```

What I would like to obtain is something like the new column `group`. The main problem is that in my sequence I do not in advance how many "subsequences with `event == 1` " there will be or how long they will be.

This is what I would like to have as a final result:

```
group = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)
data.frame(df, group)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not very readable...

```r
library("tidyverse")

x = c(10, 9 ,8,8,8,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,12)
event = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
t = 1:length(x)
df = data.frame(x, event,t)

df %>%
  # `cumsum` detects the start of a new event (a switch from 0 to 1)
  mutate(group = event * cumsum((event == 1 & lag(event, default = 0) == 0)))
#>     x event  t group
#> 1  10     0  1     0
#> 2   9     0  2     0
#> 3   8     1  3     1
#> 4   8     1  4     1
#> 5   8     1  5     1
#> 6   5     0  6     0
#> 7   4     0  7     0
#> 8   3     1  8     2
#> 9   3     1  9     2
#> 10  3     1 10     2
#> 11  3     1 11     2
#> 12  3     1 12     2
#> 13  3     1 13     2
#> 14  4     0 14     0
#> 15  5     0 15     0
#> 16  6     0 16     0
#> 17  7     0 17     0
#> 18  8     0 18     0
#> 19 12     0 19     0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: brilliant! you forgot the ```library('dplyr')``` at the beginning